# Is there a name for smooth map $\Pi:M\to\mathcal{L}(R^l)$ such that $\Pi(p)$ is an orthogonal projection and $\dim\Pi(p)$ is constant for all$p\in M$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, definition, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I'm reading the book "[Introduction to Differential Geometry](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Esalamon/PREPRINTS/diffgeo.pdf)" and according to the Theorem 2.6.10 (which is in the page 75), if $\Pi :M\to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^l)$ is a smooth map satisfying those conditions, then $E:=\bigcup _{p\in M}\{p\}\times \text{Im}(\Pi(p))$ is a smooth vector bundle over $M$. So I would like to know if this map has a name and if such maps appears in a more general context in the theory of manifolds.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: This is just a way of picking out a smooth vector subbundle of a (in this case trivial) vector bundle. I don't think it needs to be an orthogonal projection for this to work as long as it is smooth. I don't think this has a name more than just "the (orthogonal) projection onto a smooth subbundle". Vector subbundles are important in the theory of vector bundles so I suppose you could say this map appears all over the place but I wouldn't make special reference to it.